# Haskell - How do I cast Either return to my custom type?

Tags: haskell

The GHC and I are not friends yet. I want it to understand that my return type is my custom type.

Specifically, I want to ensure the compiler
that I am, in fact, returning an OAuth2Response. Is there an idiomatic way to achieve this?

Example:

```
data OAuth2Response = Either OAuth2Error OAuth2AccessToken

getAuthorized :: (..) -> (..) -> OAuth2Response
getAuthorized = do
  a <- nonceValidation (Returns Left OAuth2Error or Right "")
  b <- getAccessToken (Returns Left OAuth2Error or Right OAuth2AccessToken
  b
```

Compiler error message

```
• Couldn't match type ‘Either OAuth2Error OAuth2AccessToken’
                 with ‘OAuth2Response’
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
data OAuth2Response = Either OAuth2Error OAuth2AccessToken
```

I don't think this definition does what you think it does. In particular, the `Either` here does not refer to the `Either` *type constructor* defined in the Prelude, but to a *data constructor* which is defined as part of this declaration.

What I think you meant was

```
type OAuth2Response = Either OAuth2Error OAuth2AccessToken
```

ie to define a type synonym for the particular `Either` type you are interested in.

Answer (score 4):

Beyond what Robin Zigmond wrote, you will find other issues to fix, since `b` is of the wrong type to be used in a `do` block like you are using it. Some ways to fix this:

The "wrong" way: put `b` back in the monad

```
getAuthorized :: (..) -> (..) -> OAuth2Response
getAuthorized _ _ = do
  a <- nonceValidation (Returns Left OAuth2Error or Right "")
  b <- getAccessToken (Returns Left OAuth2Error or Right OAuth2AccessToken)
  return b
```

The "right" way, don't remove `b` from the monad in the first place.

```
getAuthorized :: (..) -> (..) -> OAuth2Response
getAuthorized _ _ = do
  a <- nonceValidation (Returns Left OAuth2Error or Right "")
  getAccessToken (Returns Left OAuth2Error or Right OAuth2AccessToken)
```